# How do mortar shells interact with walls?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cover, firearms

So, in a recent Pathfinder game, there was a character with an Aasen mortar launcher. Said launcher states:

> After the point of impact is determined, the shell explodes and deals 6d6 points of bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage to all creatures in a 30-foot radius (Reflex DC 20 for half).

How does this interact with walls?  Do creatures in total cover take damage?  Obviously, the weapon doesn't damage non-creature objects, so the cover itself cant be destroyed.  Is there a non-magical equivalent of the rule for emanation spells that they need line of effect to affect things?

Comment: Is the mortar Core or in a supplement?

Comment: Pretty sure the mortar is from Reign of Winter, which is set on Earth during WW1. http://www.archivesofnethys.com/EquipmentWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Aasen%20mortar

Comment: @YogoZuno Yes, that's correct.  It's from the *Rasputin Must Die!* module.

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the standard rules for [Cover](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Cover). In part, that says

> Cover grants you a +2 bonus on Reflex saves against attacks that originate or burst out from a point on the other side of the cover from you. Note that spread effects can extend around corners and thus negate this cover bonus.

Also, although it's not explicit, the mortar effect behaves similar to a burst effect, as defined in the [Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/) rules.

> A burst spell affects whatever it catches in its area, including creatures that you can’t see. It can’t affect creatures with total cover from its point of origin (in other words, its effects don’t extend around corners). The default shape for a burst effect is a sphere, but some burst spells are specifically described as cone-shaped. a burst’s area defines how far from the point of origin the spell’s effect extends.

As an aside, despite what the mortar's rules say...I would also have it affect objects.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71753/discussion-on-answer-by-yogozuno-how-do-mortar-shells-interact-with-walls).