# Do explosions near the edge of a spell's range let a spell affect things outside its range?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, area-of-effect

Normally spells that, for example, affect a 30' burst affect a sphere centered around a point chosen within range.  What if you pick a point near the edge of your range, such that the appropriately shaped sphere would extend beyond the edges?  Does the spell efffectively have a larger maximum range in such cases?

Comment: [Related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113412/how-do-mortar-shells-interact-with-walls/)

Answer (score 7):

## No

Actually, emanation spells cast near the edge of their range take on a weird shape that is the set of spaces they would have affected less those outside the spell's range.  The edge of such a region can be found by tracing the [line of interpenetration](http://sccs-dcg.weebly.com/intersections-of-solids.html) between the spell's ordinary region of effect and a sphere whose radius is the range of the spell centered at the caster.

This is a consequence of the rules for spells' range descriptors:

> ### Range
>
> A spell’s range indicates how far from you it can reach, as defined in the range entry of the spell description. a spell’s range is the maximum distance from you that the spell’s effect can occur, as well as the maximum distance at which you can designate the spell’s point of origin. **If any portion of the spell’s area would extend beyond this range, that area is wasted.**

(emphasis added)

Comment: Wow, I must admit, I had never encountered that bit of text before. Not what I understood.

Comment: That's definitely part of the rules that are houseruled in every game I run.